# Force SSL for specific routes in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to force SSL on **all routes** in my application except for `landing#index`.

In `config/application.rb`, I have:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Then in `landing_controller.rb`, I have:

```
force_ssl :except => :index
```

However, all routes are still being redirected to `https`.

Does anyone know how to conditionally force SSL in a Rails 3.1+ application?

**Solution:**

Add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
```

Add the following to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => [ /\/$/ ], :strict => true
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I asked a similar question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877976/rails-3-2-force-ssl-except-on-landing-page/10899219#10899219) and was told to use https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer.  I haven't tried it out yet, but based on the readme, it appears to solve your problem of conditionally enforcing ssl on certain routes.

Comment: Cheers to that! Fixed with the following line in `config/application.rb`: `config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => [ /\/$/ ], :strict => true`

Answer (score 6):

Rails 4 with ActiveAdmin 1.0b, I modified config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
config.before_filter :force_ssl_redirect, if: :https_enabled?
```

`force_ssl_redirect` is defined in  actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb and is what Rails' `force_ssl` class method calls.

`https_enabled?` defined in my application_controller.rb:

```
def https_enabled?
  ENV['HTTPS_ENABLED'] == 'true'
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it this way:

**controller**

```
force_ssl :except => :index
```

**view**

supposing your index path name is **index_landing_path**

```
<%= link_to 'Landing', index_landing_path, :protocol => 'http' %>
```

Comment: I've tried that approach but all requests are still redirected to `https`. I added `force_ssl :except => :index` to my controller to no avail.