# Rails 3.2 force_ssl except on landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I want to enforce SSL on all routes except my landing page.  I tried setting force_ssl in all my controllers, and for the controller that contains root, I did:

force_ssl :except => :index

However, after I deployed this to my staging app on Heroku, my app is still enforcing ssl on the home page.  Is there something else that needs to be done to disable ssl on that specific route?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL for specific routes in Rails 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605407/force-ssl-for-specific-routes-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) gem will help you

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but based on the readme, it appears to do what I need.  Thanks!