# force_ssl in production.rb - how to override in controller to just be http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my production.rb, I have

```
  config.force_ssl = true
```

and would like to provide exceptions. It looks like this should work (can't find how to get back to 3.2.19):

```
class ApiItemsController < ApplicationController

  force_ssl except: :get_item_test
```

but it doesn't. I've seen [Rails 3.2 force_ssl except on landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877976/rails-3-2-force-ssl-except-on-landing-page) but really don't want to be adding gems for such a trivial thing. How do I get this to work?

---

#### edit 1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to make specialized exceptions using `config.force_ssl = true` because Rails uses [rack-ssl](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl), which sets the [Strict-Transport-Security header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). You probably don't want to disable this for landing pages, anyway, as [Google now uses this as a ranking signal](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html).

Comment: @timpone Not the "easy way" with `config.force_ssl = true`. You could put the non-TLS page on its own subdomian, or just cobble together your own solution. The code for rack-ssl is surprisingly simple (https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl/blob/master/lib/rack/ssl.rb). The problem is the Strict-Transport-Security header is pretty nice to have. Just out of curiosity, why disable it at all?

Comment: The gem you pointed out would probably be a good solution, but you lose the Strict-Transport-Security header, I'm guessing (I haven't tried it)

Comment: You would also be unable to share cookies between the secure and non pages, unless you completely disable secure cookies (not a great plan). I don't know if this matters to you, or not. I would push back on the non-TLS requirement, if it were me and it seemed technologically feasible.

Comment: well - longer answer - we're hosted on a heroku and it's clear that there something that they do incorrectly with how they manage ssl endpoints as we've seen two instances of busted https (invalid certificates). It's possible that there's an issue on the client but not sure. In terms of our app, we have a section which requires auth which I'd like to have run over https but we also have a section  that are custom javascript files loaded onto customers site. As you could imagine, these latter are not being served up by heroku.

Comment: One of the clients was getting an error when accessing heroku's admin section (above in edit). The non-sharing of cookies would be ok. Pretty concerned about the heroku error but didn't have time to look at more last night.

Comment: You might consider putting the admin on it's own subdomain. It will solve this issue, as well as give you "free" protection against XSS and CSRF (http://daniel.populr.me/subdomain-boxing?ad). A lot of work, I know, but an option (still breaks cookies).

Comment: was looking into that on heroku and don't think it's possible.

Comment: Not sure about your specific scenario, or cert, but I'm pretty sure I've done it before (haven't used Heroku in ages). Have you seen https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#dns-and-domain-configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

@brad-werth is totally right that HTS headers make this something you probably don't want to do. But I keep wanting to do it anyway so here's what I've learned:

On Rails 5 (according to the [ActionDispatch::SSL docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html) ):

```
config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> request { request.path =~ /health_check/ } } }
```

In Rails 4 (and some Rails 3 versions) you have to use a separate gem. Or if it's possible to do what you need in a middleware you could try something like this:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 'ActionDispatch::SSL', 'HealthCheck'

# app/middleware/health_check.rb
class HealthCheck
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    if env['REQUEST_PATH'] == '/health_check'
      return [200, {}, []]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Some versions of Rails 3 reportedly support something [like this](http://robforman.com/how-to-setup-a-public-and-http-version-health-check-while-still-using-global-force_ssl-in-rails-for-elastic-load-balancer/):

```
config.ssl_options = { exclude: proc { |env| env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/health_check')} }
```

To answer the actual asked question the `config.force_ssl` setting in the environment is [quite different](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/14-config-force_ssl-is-different-than-controller-force_ssl) from using `force_ssl` in a controller and can't be overriden that way.