# How to validate client certificate request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, security, ssl-certificate

I have a Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku server. As I'm testing the app with SSL certificate, I added a non-paid one like this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#testing-your-certificate) explains, and forced the server app to use SSL with RackSSL gem.

So, I also have an Android client and I have some doubts:

1. How do I verify if the client request is using the same certificate?
2. How do I force SSL only on specific Rails routes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1, do as suggested in the guide: Visit the endpoint and look at the certificate that gets served up (it should be the one you added). Note that the certificate is not different depending on the client accessing Heroku, it's something that Heroku serves up to clients accessing the endpoint so you can verify this using either a normal desktop browser or your smartphone.

Ad. 2, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605407/force-ssl-for-specific-routes-in-rails-3-1) which suggests [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer).

Comment: I added a certificate and rack-ssl-enforcer. However, I've been able to get all data of ruby server routes as when I do not have a certicate added